# VBA: For loop hiding rows not working

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get my VBA code to work. I need to find blocks in my text that are 12 rows long (see picture).

I'd like to hide all the rows that are not these blocks and seperate these blocks with a blank space. One block is 12 rows (for example A13181:A13192, A13168:A13179 etc). Between these blocks are few rows of text, but not always. The data is poorly sorted so all the row data is in the first cell of the row, so we should only look for data in A column.

Block:

First row: Sopimustunnus ja hoitokonttori...

Last row:  Lyhennyssitoumuksen päättymispäivä...

https://pasteboard.co/HqA9kxI.jpg

My problem is the second if statement. I'm having problems making the block visible

```
Public Sub Luotonpurkukorko2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Luottowb As Workbook
Dim Luottosht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim hidRow As Boolean

Set Luottowb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Luottosht = Sheets("Sheet0")

'Finds the last row
lastRow = Luottosht.Cells(Luottosht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Set all rows to visible
Luottosht.Rows.Hidden = False

'Default hidden to TRUE
hidRow = True

For i = 1 To lastRow


     If Left(Luottosht.Cells(i, "A").Offset(1, 0), 8) = "Sopimust" Then
        hidRow = True
    End If

    If Left(Luottosht.Cells(i, "A"), 19) = "Lyhennyssitoumuksen" Then
    hidRow = False
    End If

    'Hide/Unhide rows
    Luottosht.Rows(i).Hidden = hidRow

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your loop to this:

```
For i = 1 To lastRow    

    If Left(Luottosht.Cells(i, "A"), 19) = "Lyhennyssitoumuksen" Then
        hidRow = False
    Else
        hidRow = True
    End If    
    Luottosht.Rows(i).Hidden = hidRow

Next i
```

or even the whole in one line:

```
For i = 1 To lastRow 
Luottosht.Rows(i).Hidden = CBool(Left(Luottosht.Cells(i, "A"), 19) <> "Lyhennyssitoumuksen")
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code hides everything except the "Lyhennyssitoumuksen" row. To keep the block of 12 +1 blank visible you can try this:

```
Public Sub Luotonpurkukorko2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Luottowb As Workbook
Dim Luottosht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim hidRow As Boolean

Set Luottowb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Luottosht = Sheets("Sheet0")

'Finds the last row
lastRow = Luottosht.Cells(Luottosht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Set all rows to visible
Luottosht.Rows.Hidden = False

'Default hidden to TRUE
hidRow = True

For i = 1 To lastRow

restart:

'if statement to check for 12 rows in block
If Left(Luottosht.Cells(i, "A"), 8) = "Sopimust" And Left(Luottosht.Cells(i, "A").Offset(11, 0), 19) = "Lyhennyssitoumuksen" Then

'keeps 12 rows + 1 blank row
        i = i + 13

'restart the check incase there are multiple blocks of 12 rows adjacent to eachother
        GoTo restart
    End If

    'Hide/Unhide rows
    Luottosht.Rows(i).Hidden = hidRow
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```